# How to find all path from Source node java code

Tags: java, breadth-first-search

I have `HashMap` of input

```
static HashMap<Integer, List<Integer> > map = new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>();
```

Basic input is like this:

```
1 :: [2, 11] , 2 :: [1, 3] , 3 :: [2, 11, 5] , 4 :: [11, 12] , 5 :: [6, 7, 3] , 6 :: [5, 7] , 7 :: [5, 6] , 8 :: [12, 10] , 9 :: [12, 10] , 10 :: [8, 9] , 11 :: [1, 3, 4] , 12 :: [4, 8, 9]
```

Which shows from 1, I can go to 2 or 11, from 2 to 1 or 3...

I need to find maximum length of node we can travel, starting from 1...

Comment: good question kamesh

Comment: The answer is: infinite. You can go from 1 to 2, then from 2 to 1, then from 1, to 2, then from 2 to 1 ad infinitum. Seriously, if you want a more constructive answer, you need to define your problem clearly, and show what you have tried. We won't do your homework.

Comment: JB Nizet : you cannot go to node once you visit it..

Comment: @kamesh I've removed my answer as I interpreted your question wrong and it doesn't solve your problem. You may want to take a look at [Longest Path Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) for possible things you could try..

Comment: @JBNizet You got any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i code a program to solve this problem. I have assume that there is no infinite loop.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;

class Kavi {

    static HashMap<Integer, List<Integer> > map = new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>();

    static HashMap<Integer, HashSet<Integer> > nodeValuesMap=new HashMap<Integer, HashSet<Integer>>();

    static HashMap<Integer, HashSet<Integer> > allPossibleTraversedNodes=new HashMap<Integer, HashSet<Integer>>();


    static HashMap<Integer, List<Integer> > putVal()
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> list;
        list=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(2); list.add(4);
        map.put(1, list);

        list=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(3);list.add(5); list.add(6);
        map.put(2, list);

        list=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(6);
        map.put(3, list);

        list=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(3);list.add(5); list.add(6);
        map.put(4, list);

        list=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(6);
        map.put(5, list);
        return map;
    }


    public static void recurs(int node)
    {
            ArrayList<Integer> list=(ArrayList<Integer>) map.get(node);
                    if(list==null)
                        return;

            if(nodeValuesMap.get(node)==null)
            {
                HashSet<Integer> nodeSet=new HashSet<Integer>();
                nodeSet.addAll(list);
                nodeValuesMap.put(node,nodeSet );
                  for(Integer i:nodeSet)
                    recurs(i);
            }

            else
            {
                HashSet<Integer> nodeSet=nodeValuesMap.get(node);
                nodeSet.add(node);
                nodeValuesMap.put(node, nodeSet);

            }

    }



    public static void main(String[]
            args){

        putVal();
        for(int i=1;i<=map.size();i++)
        {
            recurs(i);

            HashSet<Integer> tempNodeSet=new HashSet<Integer>();
            for(int j=1;j<=map.size();j++)
            {
                if(null!=nodeValuesMap.get(j))
                  tempNodeSet.addAll(nodeValuesMap.get(j));
            }
            allPossibleTraversedNodes.put(i,tempNodeSet);
            nodeValuesMap.clear();
        }

        for(int i=1;i<=allPossibleTraversedNodes.size();i++)
        {
            HashSet<Integer> nodeSet=(HashSet<Integer>) allPossibleTraversedNodes.get(i);
            System.out.println("Base Node := "+i +" All Possible Traversed Nodes:= ");
            for(Integer node:nodeSet)
                System.out.print(node+" , ");
            System.out.println("\n--------------------------------");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This gives the total number of nodes you can travel to from a certain node, whereas OP seems to ask for the length of the longest path you can traverse from a certain node.

Comment: If you want to find maximum node value or max number of node than iterate the HashSet. It has complete list of possible node

Comment: I mean, in your example the solution for starting at 1 is: `2, 3, 4, 5, 6` so that would be length 5. But there is no edge from 3 to 4. I think the correct answer (for starting in 1) is: `2, 3, 6` or `2, 5, 6` or `4, 3, 6`, etc. all having length 3.

Comment: Kavi, Thanks for your answer... In case of your program It gives us how many node we can travel but the requirement is to find all path from starting node (In your case it's 1) So possible routes are `[1,2,3,6] , [1,2,5,6] , [1,2,6], [1,4,3,6] , [1,4,5,6] , [1,4,6]`